# List Items individually with labels

Tags: javascript, forms, checkbox

Good Afternoon,

Im looking to create a small currently selected options element for a website, im fairly new when it comes to anything JS related.  How could I adjust the code below to list the selected items individually between their own `<label>`  tags?

```js
function checkCount(elm) {
      var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox-btn");
      var selected = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; ++i) {
        if(checkboxes[i].checked){
            selected.push(checkboxes[i].value);
        }
        }
      document.getElementById("proId").value = selected.join();
      document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = selected.length;
    }
```

```html
<label class='checkbox-inline'><input type='checkbox' class='checkbox-btn' value='1' onchange='checkCount();'></label>
    <label class='checkbox-inline'><input type='checkbox' class='checkbox-btn' value='2' onchange='checkCount();'></label>
    <label class='checkbox-inline'><input type='checkbox' class='checkbox-btn' value='3' onchange='checkCount();'></label>

    <input type="text" name="proId" id="proId">

<div>Total Selected : <span id="total">0</span></div>
```

Comment: *How could I adjust the code below to list the selected items individually between their own tags*....needs more clarification....

Comment: Sorry that was a little vaguwe :)  So whereas at the moment the selected items are listing in one INPUT box,  id like them individually listed  between their own 'div' tags

Comment: Div or label tags? I updated your question to show the invisible label tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have included below a simple solution.

```
      const listEl = document.getElementById('selected-value-list')
      let html = ''
      selected.forEach(item => {
        html += `<li>${item}</li>`
      })
      listEl.innerHTML = html
```

Things like this can be very elegantly handled by a modern tool like vue.js, so if you plan to do anything more complicated I would very much recommend investigating that.

```js
function checkCount(elm) {
      var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox-btn");
      var selected = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; ++i) {
        if(checkboxes[i].checked){
            selected.push(checkboxes[i].value);
        }
        }
      document.getElementById("proId").value = selected.join();
      document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = selected.length;

      const listEl = document.getElementById('selected-value-list')
      let html = ''
      selected.forEach(item => {
        html += `<li>${item}</li>`
      })
      listEl.innerHTML = html


    }
```

```html
<label class='checkbox-inline'><input type='checkbox' class='checkbox-btn' value='1' onchange='checkCount();'></label>
    <label class='checkbox-inline'><input type='checkbox' class='checkbox-btn' value='asdasd' onchange='checkCount();'></label>
    <label class='checkbox-inline'><input type='checkbox' class='checkbox-btn' value='bbbbb' onchange='checkCount();'></label>

    <input type="text" name="proId" id="proId">

<div>Total Selected : <span id="total">0</span></div>
<div>Selected Values:</div>
<ul id="selected-value-list">
 
</ul>
```

Comment: You are listing the index, not the value

Comment: Thats excellent.  THank you for the swift answer and the heads up on vue.js,  I will have a look at it. :)

Comment: Also it is not recommended to use for..in when accessing arrays

Comment: Oh yes sorry it is outputting index,  can this be adjusted for the Value :)

Comment: It's not actually wrapping in divs - also this code is not compatible with IE unless you use Babel

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```js
function checkCount(elm) {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox-btn");
  var selected = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; ++i) {
    if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
      selected.push(checkboxes[i].value);
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("proId").value = selected.join();
  if (selected.length > 0) {
    document.getElementById("tags").innerHTML = '<label>' +
      (selected.length > 1 ? selected.join('</label><label>') : selected[0]) + '</label>';
  }
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML=selected.length;
}
```

```css
#tags>label{ margin:2px; padding:3px; border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<label class='checkbox-inline'><input type='checkbox' class='checkbox-btn' value='1' onchange='checkCount();'></label>
<label class='checkbox-inline'><input type='checkbox' class='checkbox-btn' value='2' onchange='checkCount();'></label>
<label class='checkbox-inline'><input type='checkbox' class='checkbox-btn' value='3' onchange='checkCount();'></label>

<input type="text" name="proId" id="proId">

<div>Total Selected : <span id="total">0</span></div>
<div id="tags"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do that would be:

1. first add some tag in the label.
2. add the value on new tag when checkbok is checked.

```js
function checkCount(elm) {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox-btn");
  var selected = [];


  if (elm.checked) {
    elm.nextElementSibling.innerText = elm.value;
  } else {
    elm.nextElementSibling.innerText = '';
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; ++i) {
    if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
      selected.push(checkboxes[i].value);
    }
  }


  document.getElementById("proId").value = selected.join();
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = selected.length;
}
```

```html
<label class='checkbox-inline'>
    <input type='checkbox' class='checkbox-btn' value='1' onchange='checkCount(this);'>
    <span></span>
    </label>

<label class='checkbox-inline'>
      <input type='checkbox' class='checkbox-btn' value='2' onchange='checkCount(this);'>
      <span></span>
    </label>

<label class='checkbox-inline'>
      <input type='checkbox' class='checkbox-btn' value='3' onchange='checkCount(this);'>
      <span></span>
    </label>

<input type="text" name="proId" id="proId">

<div>Total Selected : <span id="total">0</span></div>
```

Comment: This is not actually answering the question

Comment: See my answer for the solution as far as I understand it. `list the selected items individually between their own <label> tags?`